# Сhange object in mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am writing a full stack project with react, mondodb, mongoose and nodejs.
I want to change the status to true when users click on the button, whose ID I pass to route

My function for route

```
const handleBlockUser =  () => {
    if(isCheck.length) {
      isCheck.map(async (userId) => {
        console.log(userId)
        const blockUser = await request(`/api/auth/`, 'PUT', {userId}) 
      })
    }
  }
```

request function

```
const request = useCallback(async (url, method = 'GET', body = null, headers = {}) => {
    setLoading(true)
```

my route

```
router.put('/', async (req, res) => {
  const {id} = req.body

  User.find(id)
    .then(doc=>{  
         doc.status = tableState;
         return doc.save();
     })
      .then(doc=>res.json(doc))
      .catch(err=>console.log(err))     
})
```

In the button I pass the correct ID, but in the console in the route it is undefined. Why?

Answer (score 0):

```
const request = useCallback(async (url, method = 'GET', body = null, headers = {}) => {
```

Because you haven't passed `userId` in PUT request. You have set `null` as the body. Pass `userId` here. I'm not sure what library you are using to send requets. If you use axios this article can help.

https://stackabuse.com/how-to-make-put-http-request-with-axios/